# python: The word in List can't be removed

Tags: python-2.7

As you can see, i'm trying to delete the word in a list whose length is 1 or 2, but "P" and "ye" can't be found and removed!

[image]

[image]

Comment: you're modifying the list as y ou iterate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```
li = ['of','in','a','bb','abbb']
lii = []
for i in li:
  j = len(i)
  if j == 1 or j == 2:
    lii.append(i)

for i in lii:
  li.remove(i)

print li
```

Output:

```
['abbb']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify list while you iterate through it.
But you can do something like this:

```
L = ['of', 'P', 'representig', 'the', 'subs', 'et', 'ye', 'ti']

result = [i for i in L if len(i) != 1 and len(i) != 2]
```